# Trying to do POST Request but getting error 500, do I need the Certificate file?

Tags: .net, rest, api

So im trying to do a post request to visa api. It says I need the following header:

```
// Header
Accept: application/json,application/octet-stream
Authorization: {base64 encoded userid:password}
```

I believe I have this set up correctly as shown below

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://sandbox.api.visa.com/visadirect/fundstransfer/v1/pullfundstransactions");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json,application/octet-stream";
            String username = "usernamehere";
            String password = "passwordhere";
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",encoded);
```

However when I do this on postman I have to upload both the Certificate and key file. When I do that it works on postman. My guess is since i did not do that here its not working. Is there a way to also send both the certificate and key file too along with the request?

When I run my code it gives me this error:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'
```